# stop editing of html using firebug and other tools before printing a receipt

Tags: html, printing

I need assistance from experienced php/html developers here.

My problem is this. I am able to fetch receipt amount from the database
and style it with html for a printable receipt.

However... the cashier is able to use firebug or inspect html and change the
receipt amount before the final printing.

How can i stop this and only print amount from database.

Any help will be greatly appreciated because it seems such a problem.

Comment: my suggestion is to convert the receipt as pdf and only then allow the cashier to take print out..

Comment: Don't forget to accept a solution, if you find any of them solves your problem. Feel free to ask further questions, if the answers are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

It will always be possible to forge the receipt - what you need to decide is, how much work you want to put into protecting against it.

The best, simple solution, would probably be to convert the html to a pdf, and deliver that instead.

Many years ago, I used FPDF, but there's likely a bunch of newer tools that can take a HTML string, and convert it to a PDF. Dompdf is a more full-featured alternative, but requires a bit more configuring.

I strongly advise going down this route, instead of adding javascript disable-right-click hacks and similar. If it's HTML shown in a browser, it will be easy to modify, no matter the amount of javascript protection you add on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, I recommend converting HTML to PDF. It's relatively easy to do.

I've used both [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (free and opensource) and [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) (commercial, costly, and supports more print-specific CSS).

In both cases, the process is fairly simple:

1. Create CSS specific to printing (e.g. specify the paper size)
2. Either generate the HTML ahead of time, or make it accessible via HTTP
3. Make a system call to invoke the tool (wkhtmltopdf or princexml) either providing the HTML directly or via HTTP.
4. The tool returns a PDF, which you send through the browser to be printed.